# Viewing pull requests that I need to comment on

Tags: github

Does anyone know of a way in GitHub to see pull requests were I am mentioned and either I have not yet commented or commits have been added since I last commented?

Answer (score 2):

If you watch a repository like this, you'll be notified by **everything** that happens on that particular repo:

[image]

New commits will appear on [your on-site dashboard](https://github.com) and comments on commits/issues/PRs (by the way "PR" stands for "Pull Request) as well as opened/closed/merged PRs and issues will come up both by e-mail and on your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the response.